# валидация формы?

Tags: django

какой код нужно прописать что бы вывести ошибку это не число мой вариант не проходит

```
    def clean_price(self):
    price = self.cleaned_data['price']
    if price < 1:
        raise ValidationError('Цена не может быть ниже 1')
    elif not isinstance(price, int):
        raise ValidationError('Это не число!')
    return price
```

Comment: Почему ваш вариант не проходит?

Comment: не знаю, не работает elif not isinstance(price, int):